# Error in using the step_bacl+aic function from the olsrr library in R

Tags: r, dataframe, olsrr

I am trying to run the `ols_steb_back_aic` function in r from the olsrr library. However when I do so I get the error:

> Error in if (aics[minc] < aic_f) { : the condition has length > 1

What exactly does this mean and what should I check for to fix it? My data is put into a large data frame and I was able to use the function just fine until I added an additional 'factor' variable. I did make sure to manually make the new factor a variable and when checking it's type it comes back as a 2 level factor. I can run `ols_step_forward_aic` and `ols_steb_back_aic` with no issues.